# How can I update the modal of a content dynamically using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a pizza application. I have created a modal in a separate components folder. My modal looks like this:[image]

I added some dummy image, title, and ingredient content to enable me to style the modal. I have my pizza container which looks like this: [image]

What I am trying to do is show my modal upon the click of the select button but with the image, title and ingredients description of the selected component. My pizza component is functional component and I know I would need to change it to a class-based component to be able to handle events. How do I go about updating the content dynamically in the modal and not just showing the dummy content I set in order to style the modal.

This is the JSX code for my Pizza component. Its a functional component.

```
const pizza = (props) => {
  return (
   <div className={styles.Pizza}>
     <h1>Pizza</h1>
     <div className={styles.PizzaContainer}>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={halfHalf} alt="half-half"/>
          <h1>Half & Half pizza</h1>
          <p>Two pizzas in one</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦4,800</h3>
          <button>Create</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={chickenCurry} alt="chickencurry"/>
          <h1>Chicken Curry</h1>
          <p>Red onions, bell peppers, chicken, pineapple, mozzarella, tomato sauce, curry, chili peppers</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦3,100</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={pepperoniFresh} alt="pepperonifresh"/>
          <h1>Pepperoni Fresh</h1>
          <p>Pepperoni, mozzarella, green peppers, pizza sauce</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦2,700</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={chickenBbq} alt="chickenbbq"/>
          <h1>Chicken BBQ</h1>
          <p>Chicken, red onions, corn, mozzarella, bbq sauce, tomato sauce</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦2,700</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
         <img src={sharwarmaPizza} alt="sharwarma"/>
          <h1>Shawarma Pizza</h1>
          <p>Mayonnaise & ketchup, spicy chicken, red onions, tomatoes, mozzarella</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦3,100</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={chickenSuya} alt="chickensuya"/>
          <h1>Chicken Suya</h1>
          <p>Mayonnaise, spicy sauce, spicy chicken, bell peppers, red onions, suya sauce, tomato sauce, mozzarella, suya spice</p>
         </div>
        <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦2,700</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
           <img src={pepperoni} alt="pepperoni"/>
           <h1>Pepperoni</h1>
           <p>Pepperoni, mozzarella, tomato sauce</p>
         </div> 
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦2,700</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={beefSuya} alt="beefsuya"/>
          <h1>Beef Suya</h1>
          <p>Mayonnaise, spicy sauce, spicy meatballs, bell peppers, red onions, mozzarella, suya sauce, tomato sauce, suya spice</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦2,700</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={chickenSupreme} alt="chickensupreme"/>
          <h1>Chicken Supreme</h1>
          <p>Spicy sauce, chicken and spicy chicken, mushrooms, bell peppers, olives, red onions, mozzarella, tomato sauce</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦3,100</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
         <img src={sweetChiliChicken} alt="sweetchillichicken"/>
          <h1>Sweet Chili Chicken</h1>
          <p>Spicy sauce, chicken, chili pepper, mozzarella, sweet chili sauce, tomato sauce</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦2,700</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={spicyMixedPizza} alt="spicymixed"/>
          <h1>Spicy Mixed Pizza</h1>
          <p>Spicy          sauce, spicy meatballs, spicy chicken, chili pepper, corn, mozzarella, buffalo sauce, tomato sauce</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦3,100</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={margherita} alt="margherita"/>
          <h1>Margherita</h1>
          <p>Mozzarella, tomato sauce</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦2,200</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={superMeaty} alt="supermeaty"/>
          <h1>Super Meaty</h1>
          <p>Chicken, pepperonni, sausages, mozzarella, tomato sauce</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦3,100</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={cheesyChicken} alt="cheesychicken"/>
          <h1>Cheesy Chicken</h1>
          <p>Chicken, tomatoes, cheddar, mozzarella, cheese sauce</p>
         </div> 
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦2,700</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={cheeseBurger} alt="cheeseburger"/>
          <h1>Cheeseburger Pizza</h1>
          <p>Beef, tomatoes, red onions, cheddar, mozzarella, mayonnaise & ketchup, tomato sauce</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦3,100</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={meatyOverload} alt="meatyoverload"/>
          <h1>Meaty Overload</h1>
          <p>Spicy sauce, pepperonni, spicy meatballs, chicken, sausages, mozzarella, tomato sauce</p>
         </div> 
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦3,400</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={meatyBbq} alt="meatybbq"/>
          <h1>Meaty BBQ</h1>
          <p>Beef, pepperonni, sausages, mozzarella, bbq sauce, tomato sauce</p>
         </div> 
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦3,100</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={hawaiian} alt="hawaiin"/>
          <h1>Hawaiian</h1>
          <p>Chicken, pineapple, mozzarella, sweet chili sauce, tomato sauce</p>
         </div>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦2,700</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
          <img src={veggieOverload} alt="veggie"/>
          <h1>Veggie Overload</h1>
          <p>Mushrooms, bell peppers, corn, olives, red onions, tomatoes, mozzarella, tomato sauce</p>
         </div> 
         <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
          <h3>from ₦2,700</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  )
}
```

This is the JSX code for my modal Component. The modal component is a class-based component.

```
class pizzaModal extends Component {
  state = {
    selected: "small"
  }
  toggleHandler = (size)=> ()=>{
    this.setState({
            toggle: size
        });
  }
  render (){
    let attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer]
    if(this.state.toggle==='small'){
      attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer, styles.Small]
    }
    if(this.state.toggle==="medium"){
      attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer, styles.Medium]
    }
    if(this.state.toggle==="large"){
      attachedClasses=[styles.ImageContainer, styles.Large]
    }
    return (
      <div className={styles.Pizzamodal}>
          <div className={styles.ModalContainer}>
            <div className={attachedClasses.join(' ')}>
              <img  src={pizzapicture} alt="pizzapicture"/>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.DetailsContainer}>
              <div>
                <div className={styles.TextDetails}>
                  <h1>Chicken Curry</h1>
                  <p>Red onions, bell peppers, <br/> chicken, pineapple, mozarella, <br/> tomatosauce, curry, chilli peppers.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                <div className={styles.Form}>
                <form className={styles.switchButton}>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="small" value="small" onChange={this.toggleHandler("small")}
                            checked={this.state.toggle==="small"}/>
                  <label for="small">Small</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="medium" value="medium" onChange={this.toggleHandler("medium")}
                            checked={this.state.toggle==="medium"}/>
                  <label for="medium">Medium</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="large" value="large" onChange={this.toggleHandler("large")}
                            checked={this.state.toggle==="large"}/>
                  <label for="large">Large</label>
                </form>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.orderButton}>
                  <button>Add to basket for ₦4,100</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I just started learning react and this is my first major project.

Comment: U might wanna look into react portals which you can use to create a reusable modal component. Further it can be given dynamic values from any components state or props.

Comment: I am just hearing about this today. I would make more research about this. Thank you.